# Command prompt carriage returns

Tags: terminal, dos, prompt

I find it very difficult to read the command line, and am I wondering if there is a way to force 2 carriage returns after I press the Enter key, to space it out more.

I am using Windows 7 command line, but also ssh into a virtual box running linux.
I find the git outputs esp hard to read.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up on Linux variable PS1 for example as

```
PS1='\n `echo -n \[\e[1\;33m\]` \t`echo \[\e[0m\]` \h \$'
```

or just add newline in the beginning of the PS1 variable in your `.bashrc`:

```
PS1="\n$PS1"
```

Comment: Thanks @Jakuje that did it! I added PS1="\n$PS1" to my  .bashrc file in my home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps with your virtual linux and git output, but you can define the PROMPT to issue a newline before the standard `c:\path>` prompt.

```
prompt $_$P$G
```

Comment: nice one - it works on my Windows prompt, but didn't take effect on my virtual box.